# Copy/paste clipboard software with a special feature

Tags: windows, gratis, clipboard, copy-paste

Is there a lightweight/freeware **copy/paste clipboard manager** that does this:

Select `Hello Blabla` (i.e. two words separated by a space)

[Copy shortcut]

[Paste1 shortcut] => pastes `Hello`
[Paste2 shortcut] => pastes `Blabla`

---

I would like to **not** have to select `Hello` and `Blabla` separately and copy them separately.

Comment: Welcome aboard. As with almost all new guys, you have forgotten to tell us which o/s this app should run on. It would also help if you tell us whether it must be free, or if you have  a budget. As you are quite active on Stack Overflow, including the C++ tag, I can tell you that the best free Windows clipboard manager, bar none, is Ditto. You can get the source code [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ditto-cp/files/Ditto/3.21.185.0/DittoSource_3_21_185_0.zip/download) and edit it yourself, or you can request the author to implement your feature. Good question !

Comment: Thank @Mawg for your answer! I have set the tag Windows, should I also mention this in the question?

Comment: Yes. You might also consider the [tag:gratis] tag. Check out Ditto. It does not do what you want, but it beats the bejazus out of whatever you are currently using.  A great question & I hope you find an answer, but I strongly suspect you will have to modify Ditto or request such a feature

Comment: gratis tag was already added ;) Thanks for the info about Ditto I'm going to use that!

Comment: @Mawg considering to write up an answer, so we can cleanup the comments (and Basj can accept the answer)?

Comment: @Mawg I tried Ditto, it's very nice, but usually for such tasks I am more looking for a more lightweight tool (Ditto is 39 MB uncompressed, i was hoping 200 kB :)) Also, I don't find how to limit the number of saved items (I tried *Options > Maximum number of saved copies > 2* but it didn't solve it), and last thing: deleting the history UX takes at least 6 clicks and 6 mousemoves, whereas I think it should be possible to do it in 1 or 2 actions. Sorry for these comments, I know the answer: I should fork it ;)

Comment: You are really concerned over 39mB disk space??? Even on a USB stick, I can't understand that, but, obviously, your mileage does vary "I don't find how to limit the number of saved items " - yes, you use *Options > Maximum number of saved copies*" and "deleting the history UX takes at least 6 clicks and 6 mousemoves" I just open it (do you count those clicks?), `ctrl+a`, then `del`, then `y` - is that really so laborious?  I can't understand why you would want to do that, especially often - it sort of defeats the point of a clipboard manager, IMO

Comment: Obviously, we have widely differing opinions, but that's fine, and I mean no offence. I would be very interested to hear what you recommend as a clipboard manager - I am always on the lookout for good apps.

Comment: Now that I'm reading my comment again, sorry for this "<ranting mode on>" comment @Mawg ;) I tend to be too focused on details sometimes! Thanks again for your advice, and I'll post another comment or answer if I find the perfect clipboard manager I'm looking for.

Comment: None taken (+1) :-) I do like your question (and have starred it), but I search compulsively for apps & revisit my most important categories a few times a year. There simply is not anything more full featured than Ditto for Windows. Please, do, let me know of any potential rivals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditto seems to be a cool software, as mentioned in the comments, by I'm looking for a more minimalist tool.

We just wrote this with a friend: [CopyCopyPastePaste](https://github.com/josephernest/copycopypastepaste) on Github, open-source.

It finally doesn't exactly do what I asked in the question, but something very similar.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, to help others who read this question in future

Answer (score 2):

As the requirement is quite specific, the easiest route for you is probably to write a custom Autohotkey script for this, or modify one of the existing ones.

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/45132-how-to-create-a-mini-clipboard-manager-using-autohotkey/